# iOS13 - UITableView + UISearchController with custom hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling behavior

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, ios13

On iOS 13, if you set `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` to true, the view controller will hide the search bar, and you have to scroll down to reveal it.
If you set it to `false` then it is immediately shown and it won't disappear.

I think this is a reasonable behavior, assuming that the end users are all versed in the way the Apple products work. Given that's not seem to be the case, I would like to show the searchbar at first visit, but then if the user starts scrolling up, the search bar is hidden. So this is a mixed behavior of the true/false.

This worked on iOS12, where I set the `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true` in the `viewDidAppear`, but now on iOS 13 it's not the case. The table scrolls, but the searchbar stays on top instead of scrolling it together with the tableview(btw this is only because the screen is not rendered again).

Any idea how to go about it? I tried changing the content offset of the tableview, but no luck really.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after adding following lines in `viewDidLoad()` method:

`navigationController!.navigationBar.sizeToFit()`

No need to specify `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` as I think by default it is `true`, but if you still see the search bar then you can set it `true` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as you and looks like such issue appears in iOS 13 only. In iOS 14 your solution works perfectly.
To make it work in iOS 13 you need to add

```
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout() // add this line
```

in `viewDidAppear`

It works for me in simulator iOS 13.7 I hope it work for you as well.